# Passar dados entre forms

Tags: c#, winforms, login

Estou elaborando meu TCC e precisava fazer com que os dados coletados no cadastro servissem como login, porque ainda não temos servidor pra guardar estes dados, então eles estão sendo feitos com `ArrayList`.

**Segue o código:**

```
public partial class Frm_cadastro : Form
{
    ArrayList Nome = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList Senha = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList Email = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList DataNascimento = new ArrayList();
    int Contador= 0; 

    public Frm_cadastro()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nome, email, senha;
        nome = txt_nome.Text;
        email = txt_email.Text;
        senha = txt_senha.Text;
        if (nome.Trim().Length == 0 || email.Trim().Length == 0 || senha.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Todos os campos devem estar preenchidos!", "Aviso");

        }
        else if (chk_termos.Checked == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Os termos devem ser aceitos!");
        }
        else
        {
            Frm_confirmacao Confirmacao = new Frm_confirmacao();
            Confirmacao.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        Nome.Add(txt_nome.Text);
        Senha.Add(txt_senha);
        Email.Add(txt_email);
        DataNascimento.Add(dtp_data_nascimento.Text);
    }

    private void btn_voltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form Principal = Application.OpenForms["frm_principal"];
        Principal.Show();
        this.Dispose();
    }

    private void Frm_cadastro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

e aqui o da tela de login, como ainda não consegui fazer ele capitar as variáveis, dei uma condição especifica, mas não era assim que queria

```
private void lnk_esqueceu_senha_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frm_esquecer_senha Senha = new Frm_esquecer_senha();
        Senha.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frm_cadastro Cadastro = new Frm_cadastro();
        Cadastro.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void btn_entrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email, senha;
        email = txt_login.Text;
        senha = txt_senha.Text;

        if (email.Trim().Length == 0 || senha.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Todos os campos devem estar preenchidos!", "Aviso");
        }
        else if (email != "Administrador" && senha != "Adm@2014")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("E-mail ou senha incorretos!");

        }
        else
        {
            Frm_pagina_inicial Inicial = new Frm_pagina_inicial();
            Inicial.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }

    private void txt_senha_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_senha.PasswordChar = '*';
    }
```

Comment: Tem certeza que vai usar ArrayList? Está usando o .Net 1.1?

Comment: Sim porque é o que aprendemos nas aulas, e como não temos banco usamos o arraylist. Usk o VB 2010 mas não sei se é o 1.1

Comment: Se você está usando o Visual Studio 2010 (e não VB 2010), está usando o .Net 4.0. Desde a versão 2.0 o ArrayList foi substituído pelo List<T> porque o anterior é considerado inseguro e possui problemas de performance. A ÚNICA razão para usar ArrayList seria não ter um .Net mais atual disponível, que não é o caso. Além disso, vejo alguns outros problemas no código, mas para poder te ajudar, precisamos de informação mais específica de qual a dificuldade está tendo.  Se maiores detalhes ninguém vai conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: dê andamento à questão por favor

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução rápida seria criar uma classe estática para armazenar as informações que vc quer, como lista de emails, senhas e nomes, essas seriam acessíveis de qualquer lugar do sistema.

#### Primeira coisa: tirar o `ArrayList`

E substituir por `List<string>` e também pluralizar os nomes das variáveis que representam listas. A inicialização então ficaria assim:

```
List<string> Nomes = new List<string>();
List<string> Senhas = new List<string>();
List<string> Emails = new List<string>();
List<string> DataNascimentos = new List<string>();
```

#### Mover as listas para uma classe estática

Crie outro arquivo e mova as listas para outra classe, fazendo elas também estáticas:

```
public static class Login
{
    public static List<string> Nomes = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> Senhas = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> Emails = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> DataNascimentos = new List<string>();
}
```

#### Mudar a forma de adicionar dados à lista

Na parte que diz:

```
    Nome.Add(txt_nome.Text);
    Senha.Add(txt_senha);
    Email.Add(txt_email);
    DataNascimento.Add(dtp_data_nascimento.Text);
```

Troque por:

```
    Login.Nomes.Add(txt_nome.Text);
    Login.Senhas.Add(txt_senha.Text);
    Login.Emails.Add(txt_email.Text);
    Login.DataNascimentos.Add(dtp_data_nascimento.Text);
```

Dessa forma você pode simplesmente chamar `Login.AlgumaCoisa` e terá as listas acessíveis de outras classes.

Answer (score 0):

primeiro, criaria uma classe para os dados de login:

```
public class Login
{
      public string Nome {get;set;}
      public string Senha {get;set;}
      public string Email {get;set;}
      public DateTime Nascimento {get;set;}
}
```

e no programa, criaria a lista de dados:

```
public partial class Frm_cadastro : Form
{
    public static List<Login> Dados = new List<Login>();

    public Frm_cadastro()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

no entanto, você tem que manter a lista de dados no form principal, que será mantido aberto durante toda a execução do programa.

ao cadastrar um novo login, adiciona a lista

no form de cadastro, você pode acessá-la utilizando:

```
Login obj = new Login();
obj.Nome = textBoxNome.Text;
//outros campos

FormPrincipal.Dados.Add(obj);
```

no form de login, você pode validar o login assim:

```
Login obj = FormPrincipal.Dados.Find(x=>x.Email == textBoxLoginEmail.Text);

if (obj != null)
{
   if (obj.Senha == textBoxLoginSenha.Text)
   {
     //Senha válida
   }
   else
   { 
    //Senha inválida
   }
}
else
{
    //email nao encotrado
}
```