# C# - Passagem de dados entre Windows Form usando ListView

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, winforms, listview

Tenho um projeto em C# Windows Form, no meu projeto eu tenho 2 telas, 1 - ListView para mostrar as informacoes, 2 Formulario para obter os dados do usuario e passar para o ListView do Form1, mas o problema e: passar as informacoes do form2 para o form1

Minha Logica:

- Obter as informacoes do usuario pelo form2 e passa-las para uma outra classe
- No Form1 eu leio as informacoes dessa outra classe e passo para o ListView

Problema:

- Obejeto do tipo `ListViewItem` sempre retorna nullo

Form2: Para obter as informacoes

```
    namespace Company
{
    public partial class Register : Form
    {
        EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();

        public Register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.idEmployee = Convert.ToInt16(this.txtId.Text);
            employee.nameEmployee = this.txtName.Text;
            employeeDAO.insert(employee);

        }

    }
}
```

Minha classe para obter as informacoes do form2 e passar para o form1: (Colocando no ListViewItem)

```
namespace Company
{
    class EmployeeDAO
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

        public void insert(Employee employee)
        {
            string id;
            string name;
            id = Convert.ToString(employee.idEmployee);
            name = employee.nameEmployee;
            String[] row = { id, name };
            item = new ListViewItem(row);
        }

        public ListViewItem read()
        {
            //This item are returning null
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Form1 para mostrar os dados no ListView: (Recebo um objeto do tipo ListViewItem e add no ListView)

```
namespace Company
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lstEmployee.View = View.Details;
            lstEmployee.FullRowSelect = true;
            lstEmployee.Columns.Add("ID", 150);
            lstEmployee.Columns.Add("Nome", 150);
            insert();
        }

        private void insert()
        {
            EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();
            ListViewItem item = employeeDAO.read();
            if (item == null)
            {
                //Always this block run
                MessageBox.Show("No Item");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item");
                lstEmployee.Items.Add(item);
            }            
        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Register register = new Register();
            register.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Alguem pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: ta bem estranho esse código aí, mas seu problema está que você cria uma instância do objeto `EmployeeDAO` e logo depois dá o `read`, é claro q ele vai estar null ou vazio.

Comment: Um formulário abre o outro, ou um é filho do outro? Entendi que tu tem um formulário com uma busca, onde informa o id do usuario e aí quer add esse usuário na listview do outro form. Isso?

Comment: Entao e que estou aprendendo, mas se eu tirar a instancia e colocar em cima do Main, ele vai criar uma outa do mesmo jeito nao vai?

Comment: @Aline um abre o outro, por exemplo quando ele inicia, abre o form principal que e a `Main`, nela estao listados todos o empregados cadastrados, na primeira vez ele vai ser nulo porque ainda nao teve nenhum cadastro, nessa mesma tela, tem um botao cadastrar! onde o usuario clica e some a `Main` e aparece o `Register` depois que eu usuario preencher os dados e cadastrar, o formulario `Register` vai passar os dados pro `Main` e vai se fechar!

Comment: dá uma olhada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13797/passar-dados-entre-forms/198273#198273

Comment: Como tu abre a Main qndo fecha o Register?

Comment: Sim, isso quando fecha o `Register` e quando inicia o sistema

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode adicionar um parâmetro não obrigatório no construtor da sua classe Main:

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Main(Dictionary<int, string> listEmployee = new Dictionary<int, string>)
    {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    lstEmployee.View = View.Details;
                    lstEmployee.FullRowSelect = true;
                    lstEmployee.Columns.Add("ID", 150);
                    lstEmployee.Columns.Add("Nome", 150);
                    insert();
    }

    private void insert()
    {          
                    foreach(var item in listEmployee)
                    lstEmployee.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(string[] {item.Key.toString(), item.Value}));    
    }

    private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    Register register = new Register();
                    register.Show();
                    this.Hide();
    }
}
```

E sua Register:

```
public partial class Register : Form
{
        Dictionary<int, string> listEmployee = new Dictionary<int, string>

        public Register()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                listEmployee.Add(Convert.toInt32(this.txtId.Text), this.txtName.Text);
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                var main = new Main(listEmployee);
        }

 }
```

Não me parece fazer sentido tu ter aquelas classe intermediária (EmployeeDAO). Além do que, na main tu instancia ele de novo, o que quer dizer que ela é um novo objeto, sem qualquer atribuição que não seja feita direto no seu construtor ou diretamente em seus atributos.